# Update a record with a single click

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am working on a CMS for a website using PHP and MySQL and have been asked if it is possible to 'publish' articles just by clicking on a button?

To make things clear, the articles may have already been entered into the database but not identified as being ready for publication. Articles for the site have a column in the db called `_'pub'_`, which is an `ENUM('n','y')`. I have created a page which lists all articles by section, article heading, date and published.

If `_'pub'_` is `'y'`, published displays **YES**, otherwise it displays **NO**

I have created an additional page that changes the state of `_'pub'_` so that it works by clicking on the **Yes** or **No** for published, but wondered if there was a way of changing the status of `_'pub'_` using javascript rather than an additional page.

I look forward to hearing any suggestions

Comment: This sounds like a job for AJAX(tm)! Edit: are you using a framework like jQuery? That would make it easier.

Comment: You can make these buttons on the same page as well. It would be still 1 click. I see no problem here

Answer (score 1):

Just use jquery like this

```
$.post("/submit.php","title='Title of post'&content='PostContent'", function(d){
  $(".output").html(d);
});
```

What that basically does is, sends the content to `submit.php` with (`$_POST['title']` and `$_POST['content']`).. and then returns the output in a div with the classname `output`

And everything happens with a single click on the same page

Comment: Famver Tags, thanks for the advice, I will do some experimenting :)

Answer (score 0):

You want the users to stay on same page, is that it?

Use ajax/jQ to:

- submit articleid that should be published
- on request-completion, change image/text in list from "no" to "yes"

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

is a good start.

regards,
//t

Comment: User 247245 Thanks for the link, this is new to me so I need to read up on it.